# How to deal with information received in two packets

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

This is the case. I want to make a game, client being made in flash and server on java. From server side, the first byte i write on the stream is the protocol id, like this:

```
try 
{
 Output.writeByte(LOGIN);
 Output.writeByte((byte)ID);
 Output.writeByte(new_position.x);
 Output.writeByte(new_position.y);
 Output.flush();
}
```

After the 'onResponse' event is triggered, the socket is read like this:

```
type:int = socket_client.readByte();
if (type == 0x1)
FP.console.log("You are logged as " + socket_client.readByte() + " in x:" + socket_client.readByte() + " y:" +  socket_client.readByte() );
else if (type == 0x2)
      FP.console.log("You are now in x:" + socket_client.readByte() + " y:" +  socket_client.readByte());
```

As you probably have guessed by now, this gives me some problems. Sometimes, server sends the information split in two, so the above code throws an EOF exception. Tracing the following code gives me sometimes this result:

```
trace("SIZE: " + socket_client.bytesAvailable);
//var type:int = socket_client.readByte();
var values:String = "";
while (socket_client.bytesAvailable > 0)
       values += socket_client.readByte() + " ";
trace(values);`
```

Values:

```
 SIZE: 1
 2 
 SIZE: 2
 2 6
```

The first '2' is the protocol id, the second and the third stands for x and y values.
Now, the question is, how can i prevent this to happen? How could i 'wait' until i have all the information needed?
Btw, on java this never happens, but i have no more control than on as3.

Comment: Sending in two packets shouldn't cause an `EOFException` unless there is something seriously wrong with the underlying framework. EOFException means that the peer has closed the connection. In any case the solution is to use a buffered output.

Comment: What i exactly get it's an Error 2030. Anyway, I dont know how to use a "buffered output", could you give me some hints please?

Comment: So it doesn't 'throw an EOF exception' at all. Please state your problem accurately. Re buffered output, see @kapustka's answer.

Comment: Sorry, i thought EOF exception was the same as "Error #2030: End of file was encountered.". Anyway, kapustka gave me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `BufferedOutputStream` in output initialization like this:

```
Output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()));
```

Comment: Yes! that single line was exactly what i needed. Thanks kapustka. My i ask you a related question? Before, i used to intanciate one DataOutputStream for writing bytes and flushing, but then i observed that each time my client received data, it was like server were accumulating new data with old data and sending them again. So the first time my client received 4 bytes, then 8, then 12, and so on. I changed that so each new stream received from the client is managed with a new DataOutputStream. Am i doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to switch your message format from `[type, data]` to `[type, length, data]`.  Then, wait to process the data until `bytesAvailable` >= `length`, otherwise put it into a buffer.

Here is an example `SOCKET_DATA` handler that uses this logic:

https://github.com/magicalhobo/Flash-CS5-mobile-proxy/blob/master/com/magicalhobo/mobile/proxy/MobileClient.as#L110

Comment: Thanks Sean. While this is not what i was looking for, i believe it will come handy in a future.

Comment: Alright, but your client is still buggy until you do that.  Any part of the network could break your message into separate packets, not just your server.

Comment: Indeed i tested it yesterday i saw that i needed this logic.